# Can't show object on Ionic

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have those mock users created:

```
private mockUsers =
    {
      "cristian@correo.com": {
        name: "Cristian Sures Vera",
        gender: "male",
        birthday: "1995-12-29",
        city: "Telde",
        phone: "686722255",
        email: "cristian@correo.com",
        type: "doctor",
        password: "1234"
      },
      "antonio@correo.com": {
        name: "Antonio Perez Perez",
        gender: "male",
        birthday: "1990-04-22",
        city: "Las Palmas",
        phone: "444555666",
        email: "antonio@correo.com",
        type: "patient",
        password: "1234",
        exercises: {}
      }
    };
  getUsers() {
    return this.mockUsers;
  }
```

And I'm trying to show it doing that:

> search.html

```
  <ion-searchbar (ionInput)="search($event)" ></ion-searchbar>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let user of users" >
      {{user}}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

> search.ts

```
  private users;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public userProvider: UserProvider) {
    this.users = userProvider.getUsers();
  }

  search(event){
    this.users = this.userProvider.getUsers();

    let val = event.target.value;

    if (val && val.trim() != ''){
      for (let key in this.users) {
        if(searchValueIsInTheUsername(this.users[key])){
          return this.users[key];
        }
      }
    }

    function searchValueIsInTheUsername(user: any) {
        return user['name'].toLowerCase().includes(val.toLowerCase());
    }
  }
```

I have to print all the users and cant use `*ngFor` because is an object and is not supported. Do I have to change the form that I return the object? Or I have another form to show all users within `*ngFor`?

All the project is public on [github](https://github.com/CrisKrus/prematureKids) on the search-patient branch

Comment: I mean when I will save the data on a real no-sql database, is correct?

Comment: But ok, you are right. This is not the question that I should do. Maybe I have to edit all

Comment: Where you store your data is really up to you, whether you use a database engine or files. While there are obvious advantages of a database engine, you may find that mock data works best for you in local files.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your api return type. If you rest api is returning list of users then it's better to store the Json in the same format. To convert the object to list and to be able to use it, make the following change:

```
private mockUsers: any[] =
[
  "cristian@correo.com": {
    name: "Cristian Sures Vera",
    gender: "male",
    birthday: "1995-12-29",
    city: "Telde",
    phone: "686722255",
    email: "cristian@correo.com",
    type: "doctor",
    password: "1234"
  },
  "antonio@correo.com": {
    name: "Antonio Perez Perez",
    gender: "male",
    birthday: "1990-04-22",
    city: "Las Palmas",
    phone: "444555666",
    email: "antonio@correo.com",
    type: "patient",
    password: "1234",
    exercises: {}
  },
  "another@correo.com": {
    name: "Another mock user",
    gender: "male",
    birthday: "1990-04-22",
    city: "Las Palmas",
    phone: "444555666",
    email: "another@correo.com",
    type: "patient",
    password: "1234",
    exercises: {}
  }
   ] ;
```